Event delay in nodejs
I read that http.createServer(); return event emitter and in normal event emitter if event emmits before register listener on it, nothing will happen, but in case of http server I registered the event after emitting it (httpServer.listen) and the listener executed normally!
here it prints "Event: listening"
const http = require("http");
const httpServer = http.createServer();

httpServer.listen(3000);

httpServer.on("listening", () => {
  console.log(`Event: listening`);
});

here it doesn't print anything (normal behavior)
const event = require("events");
const emitter = new event.EventEmitter();

emitter.emit("test");

emitter.on("test", () => {
  console.log("test event");
});

can anyone explain this behavior to me?

I think you'd have to dig around the source code if you really want the answer to this question. .listen() is probably not doing what your code is doing. You could also try httpServer.emit("listening") rather than .listen()

"I read that http.createServer(); return event emitter" not quite, it returns an instance of http.Server which extends net.Server which extends EventEmitter. Educated guess would be there's an internal queueing of events in one of those classes until a listener is subscribed, this is a common pattern in async pub/sub systems. You could even build it in a class yourself MyClass extends EventEmitter and add a listen method that flushes a queue when your overridden on method is called with a relevant handler.

Good observation! Let's investigate how node implements the listen method to see why this is the case. If we open up lib/net.js we'll see (simplified) code that looks like:
function setupListenHandle(address, port, addressType, backlog, fd, flags) {
  // ...
  defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope(this[async_id_symbol],
                             process.nextTick,
                             emitListeningNT,
                             this);
}

function emitListeningNT(self) {
  // Ensure handle hasn't closed
  if (self._handle)
    self.emit('listening');
}

Let's simplify that code (ignoring some cases that node's implementation handles better):
function setupListenHandle(address, port, addressType, backlog, fd, flags) {
  // ...
  process.nextTick(() => {
    self.emit('listening');
  });
}

With careful observation, things are starting to make sense. Node's behavior is essentially:
const event = require("events");
const emitter = new event.EventEmitter();

process.nextTick(() => {
  emitter.emit("test");
});

emitter.on("test", () => {
  console.log("test event");
});

which works exactly how you observed.

Thanks! things being clear here, does the same is applied in routes registering too (defer the actual listening to the next tick) ?
I mean that I can register the route before or after server.listen() and in both cases it works, also while using the debugger to go through the code the actual listen not start unless i finish the debugger execution

To be clear, the listening happens synchronously, but the event itself gets emitted one tick later (so that you can define the listener after running .listen()). If you found this answer useful, please accept it. To answer your second question, routing is not handled by any node internal modules, so I'm not sure what library you are specifically referring to here.
